# Replace exact word

Tags: vb.net

I want to convert this string:

```
"http://www.example.com/sms.aspx?user=joey&pass=joey123&mbno=9792234567&msg=Test"
```

to this:

```
"http://www.example.com/sms.aspx?user={0}&pass={1}&mbno={2}&msg={3}"
```

But I am getting output like this:

```
"http://www.example.com/sms.aspx?user={0}&pass={0}123&mbno={2}&msg={3}".
```

I have used the following line of code for replacing:

```
Dim SMSUrlStr As String="http://www.example.com/sms.aspxuser=joey&pass=joey123&mbno=9792234567&msg=Test"
```

e.g.  `Regex.Replace(SMSUrlStr, joey, {0})`

but it is also replacing "joey" from "joey123".

How can I make the replacement more specific?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of looking at the input as a string, you could regard it as a URI. There are methods in the framework to work with URIs, and from that we can rebuild it into the form you need:

```
Imports System.Collections.Specialized
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Web

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim s = "http://www.example.com/sms.aspx?user=joey&pass=joey123&mbno=9792234567&msg=Test"
        Dim u = New Uri(s)
        Dim q = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(u.Query)

        Dim newQ = q.AllKeys.Select(Function(p, i) p & "={" & i & "}")

        Dim newS = u.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path) & "?" & String.Join("&", newQ)

        Console.WriteLine(newS)
        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Outputs:

```
http://www.example.com/sms.aspx?user={0}&pass={1}&mbno={2}&msg={3}
```